# Is it possible to decrypt a message in APEX using asymmetric RSA algorithm?

Tags: encryption, crypto, decrypt

I know that Salesforce supports symmetric AES-based encryption(Crypto Class). What if I need to decrypt a message in salesforce which is encrypted using asymmetric RSA?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? [edit] your question to include those details.

Answer (score 3):

You can only decrypt symmetric AES-based encryption. RSA is only used for digital signatures (Crypo.sign and Crypto.verify methods).